# Max number of elements from ${1,2,3...13}$, so that no three numbers $a,b,c$ satisfy $a-b | c$. $a≠b$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

So we have a set of numbers from 1 to 13. What is the maximal number of elements from it we can choose so that no three numbers $a,b,c$ satisfy $a-b|c$. $a \ne b$.

I'm not sure how to solve this without using a brute-force method of checking every possibility. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is $a=c$ allowed ?

Comment: @Peter yes. There's no restriction on it

Comment: As a first idea, the sequence cannot contain two consecutive numbers.

Comment: The set of odd numbers seems like a good guess to start with.

Comment: Hello @johndoe . Please do not write your full question in the title; instead, write your question in the body of your post with a short description of your question in the title. Moreover, you should add your attempts and work on this problem to your post. Otherwise, you may get downvotes.

Comment: Hello @RezaRajaei. I understand your first point and it was not intentional, but I was trying to be less misleading with the title so I ended up writing the whole problem in it. I do not appreciate your second point. There is only one brute-force way to solve this question and it would have taken me bodies of text to write it down. Moreover, every brute-force searching method is the same and it is not beneficial to write it down. Furthermore, I care little about downvotes, so you (and anyone else ) can go ahead and downvote me if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is 7. This given by the set $\lbrace 1,3,5,7,9,11,13 \rbrace$. If there are 8 or more, divide the set $[13]$ into 7 boxes: $\{ 1,2\},\{ 3,4\}, …, \{11,12\}, \{13\}$. One of the boxes has to accommodate 2 numbers, giving a difference of 1.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! Why did we restrict the set to only odd numbers?

Comment: The odds seem to be the way to dodge consecutive numbers. Evens run into differences being even.